# Can EventHandler get deleted during runtime by concurrency accidents

Tags: c#, events, testing, timer, nunit

A timer triggers every millisecond and causes a dataobject to control itself, if a change is made an event is fireing. (`NowTimeCapsule : TimeCapsule : ACapsule : ICapsule`)

Dependent objects (`TimeCapsule : ACapsule : ICapsule`) have registered for that event and update themselves if nescessary. If a change is made an event is fired.

A Form adds delegates to the dependent objects Change event, if the event fires the delegate updates a textbox.

For some reason this chain breaks down - i Unittested the individual parts and i know (by throwing messageboxed) that it runs a while before breaking down.

How can i test this chain using NUnit.
Where are reasonable corners to concentrate testing on.

---

EDIT:

Found it. The timer was wrapped to catch exceptions and the invoke failed with an exception. The trigger was disposed by the wrapper. I removed the wrapper and fixed the invoke, all tests green. i will write an answer as soon as i know its stable.

Comment: I hardly suspect that EventHandlers get deleted.
Are any of the eventhandlers methods creating a new object that should be have an event assigned to? IF you are creating new objects the event handlers still point to the old ones. 
If so, unassign the old one uisng '-=' and assing it to the new object "+="

Comment: Can you provide a simple example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I am working on it, but none of the tests fails so far - so i dont have a reproduction yet. I currently suspect it is my textbox invoke.

Comment: Nah. First make sure the event is always being fired. Then if you suspect that for some reason one of your consumers isn't currentky subscribing to the event. Add some logging code in the method that fires the event to list out current subscribers. Usually a Doh moment this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updater that threw the events had a bug and crashed.

Events work fine.